# How can you delete individual indexes on properties in an Entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I know you can delete composite indexes with `gcloud datastore indexes cleanup` but what about deleting individual indexes on properties in an Entity?

For example, let's say you have been indexing a property on an entity for a while, but then you decide not to anymore and upload a new version of your app that excludes it. I presume the index is still somewhere there in a table somewhere. Is there a way to clear these out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index is updated for an entity when you put the entity.  You could put all of your entities to clear that index for all of them.

Comment: I am aware you can do that, however, that would take a very long time (and cost money) to read and put all those entities.

Comment: Yes, but that is the way it works